# Is network boot possible on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: boot, berryboot, bootloader, u-boot, multiboot

I have several RPI and want them to have a common OS shared thanks to a hotpot generated from a central computer, hence my question:

**Is network boot possible on Rasperry PI?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, the offical Raspberry Pi site wrote about it.
I don't want to write a new Tutorial about it because the already did a woderful job at it.

[Link to raspberry.org](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes)